# Importing presentation from powerpoint to google slides or libreoffice impress - issue with Cambria Math fonts for equation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, google-workspace

I am using MS PowerPoint to create presentations that have lots of maths equations. It's easy to create a presentation with MS Equation editor and they are neat. However, using PowerPoint is the only reason I need to use Microsoft windows. I am on Linux and at times it's difficult to switch over to windows just because I need to use PowerPoint for my maths presentations.

I want to import those presentations in LibreOffice Impress or Google Slides. The equations in these presentations are in the "Cambria Math" font.

I couldn't find Cambria Math fonts in Libreoffice impress. Google Slides have Cambria Maths fonts but when I import the presentation from PowerPoint to Google Slides, somehow the equations are not imported. That part of the presentation is blank.

Is there anyway I can import presentations from PowerPoint to Google Slides so that I don't have to use MS PowerPoint? It will save monthly subscription to office 365 and windows OS.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be a compatibility issue between two different kinds of presentation applications that is hard to fix.